# UAT Server Publish Error in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Could not load file or assembly '360.Business' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

[image]

Comment: Where is the 360.Business reference? do you have add it as a reference? if it is done, check the version of the assembly's dll file in bin folder with your web.config where your dll version is mentioned.

Comment: 360.Business is a business layer which is created for our project so we dont have the option to specify the dll version  in the web config file,what needs to be done ?

Comment: Clean and Re-build your project. Make sure the file is in the correct path and try again

Comment: I have tried all that it is still not working

Comment: Are you recently updated the website in UAT server? If yes, re-update the last changes with the 360.business file

Comment: I have tried that even

Comment: Did you try with undo the changes ? is it working?

Comment: NO ,its not working still

Comment: I think, the 360.Security file was modified and built in some other projects. So the project dll version might be different from the DLL in UAT server.

Comment: one moment, can you show me what are the namespaces you are include in the 360.buisness file?